# Where should I put this code that should be done in background?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I am building an app that calculates stuff.

The user will enter his/her inputs in `OperationViewController` and then he/she will click "Calculate". After calculating the results, a segue is performed to show the `ResultsViewController`.

Some of the calculations will take a long time, so I think they should be done in the background thread. And I should show a message saying that it is calculating and an activity indicator.

I also grabbed some code from somewhere that makes doing things in the background super swifty. Here is the code:

```
import Foundation
infix operator ~> {}

/**
 Executes the lefthand closure on a background thread and,
 upon completion, the righthand closure on the main thread.
 Passes the background closure's output, if any, to the main closure.
 */
func ~> <R> (
    backgroundClosure: () -> R,
    mainClosure:       (result: R) -> ())
{
    dispatch_async(queue) {
        let result = backgroundClosure()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            mainClosure(result: result)
        })
    }
}

/** Serial dispatch queue used by the ~> operator. */
private let queue = dispatch_queue_create("serial-worker", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

Then, the problem arises.

In `OperationViewController`, there is a method called `getResults`:

```
private func getResults () -> [(name: String, from: String, result: String)]? {
    // irrelevent code about getting the user's inputs from UITextFields
    return operation.calculate(input) // This will take a few seconds
}
```

The `calculate` method there requires a few seconds to return.

The Calculate button, mentioned earlier has a segue that's connected to `ResultsViewController`. I didn't explicitly call `performSegueWithIdentifier`. I just control dragged the button to the results view controller.

In `prepareForSegue`, I call `getResults`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showOperationHelp" {
        // irrelevent
    } else if segue.identifier == "showResults" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultsViewController
        vc.results = getResults()
    }
}
```

Now I tried to put the `getResults` part in a background thread by doing this:

```
} else if segue.identifier == "showResults" {
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultsViewController;
    { self.getResults() } ~> { vc.results = $0 };
}
```

But that doesn't work because `prepareForSegue` returns before the calculation finish. This means that `vc.results` is `nil` when `prepareForSegue` returns. This will cause the `ResultsViewController` to show nothing.

Another method I have tried is to put the "do in background" thingy in `getResults`:

```
private func getResults () -> [(name: String, from: String, result: String)]? {
    // irrelevent code about getting the user's inputs from UITextFields
    var results: [(name: String, from: String, result: String)]?;
    { self.operation.calculate(input) } ~> { results = $0 };
    return results
}
```

Again, `getResults` will just return `nil`.

Back then when I was writing C#, I can use the `async/await` keywords to achieve this.

I can just do something like:

```
var results = await operations.Calculate(input);
```

When execution reaches `await`, it pauses there and allows the UI thread to go on. After the async operation has finished, the execution goes back to where it had stopped and continues on.

Question: Can I do something like the above in Swift? If I can't, how can I wait until the calculations finish and show `ResultsViewController`?

Just in case you didn't understand me, I'll describe exactly what I want:

1. the user enters some inputs
2. the user taps the calculate button
3. A message shows up telling the user that it is calculating
4. Some time later
5. Calculation finishes
6. `ResultsViewController` is shown

After some trying, I can only get this:

1. the user enters some inputs
2. the user taps the calculate button
3. A message shows up telling the user that it is calculating
4. `ResultsViewController` is shown, with no results
5. Some time later
6. Calculation finishes but `ResultsViewController` don't know.

P.S. I don't know how to improve the question title...

Comment: It sounds like you should dispatch the calculation into the background in your `viewWillAppear` of your `ResultsViewController`.  This view controller should display an activity view and/or message until the calculation is done.  Once it is done, hide the activity view and show the results.  Don't forget to dispatch the UI updates on the main queue

Comment: But I don't want to pass the `operation` object to `ResultViewController` though! `ResultsViewController` should not own an operation, right? It should only have the results. Also, I want to show the activity indicator in the `OperationViewController`, not `ResultsViewController`. @Paulw11

Comment: In that case you need to use the button press to display the activity view in `OperationViewController` and dispatch the calculation into the background.  When the calculation is complete, call `performSegueWithIdentifier` to display the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing original response for clarity:

- Have the the calculate button call a method called calculate() or something that shows the activity indicator, then calls the getResults method.
- give getResults() a completionHandler, and on successful completion dismiss the activity indicator and perform the segue with the completed calculation.

Comment: _I would also recommend having the calculations performed by a separate class from either of the viewControllers._ It is! The `calculate` method belongs to the `Operation` class. However, are there other methods? Although this works, I think it is not very elegant since I have to create a property to share the result among the `@IBAction` and `prepareForSegue`. But if there isn't, that's fine as well.

Comment: yes, noticed that and clarified the response. You don't need to create a property, you can return it in the completion handler and then pass it through to your ResultsViewController